# Display validation message

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am struggling with displaying validation messages on my webpage. 
I have a javascript function which does client side validation and highlights the fields with invalid values. Besides highlighting the fields, I want to display a message on my webpage which I dont know how to do.

Here is my javascript function:

```
$(function () {

    $("#Save").click(Validate);

});

function Validate() {

var invalidValues = [];
var validValues = [];
var Code = $("#Code").val();
var Description = $("#Description").val();
var Status = $("#Status ").val();    

var requiredFields = { '#Code' : Code,
                         '#Description' : Description,
                         '#Status ' : Status };

    $.each(requiredFields, function (key, value) {
        if (value.length == 0) {
            invalidValues.push(key);
        }
        else { validValues.push(key); }
    });

        var invalidFields = invalidValues.toString();
        var validFields = validValues.toString();

    if (invalidValues.length > 0){
        $(invalidFields).addClass("highlighted");
        $(validFields).removeClass("highlighted");      
        return false;
    }
    $(validFields).removeClass("highlighted");
}
```

Here is my webpage:

```
<div>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Code
        </th>
        <td>
           <input maxlength="4" id="Code" type="text"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>
            Description
        </th>
        <td>
            <input id="Description" type="text"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>
            Status
        </th>
        <td>
            <input id="Status" type="text"/>
        </td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>  
        <th>
    </th>      
        <td>
            <button id="Save" type="button">Save</button>
        </td>        
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want to display a message at the bottom of my webpage saying "Please enter valid values for: Code". I store invalid values in a variable "invalidValues "in my js function "Validate" How can I access those values in my webpage?

I also have a few questions about what is the best way of doing validations? Client side vs server side? also, is it better to display a pop-up validation message or a highlighted message embedded on webpage?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Look at validation libraries that already exist. There are plenty out there, Some even use the HTML5 validation.

Comment: @epascarello As of now, dont have HTML5 and am limited to libraries I can use, so doing it this way.

Comment: @user793468 - How are you limited to 'libraries you can use'?  Can you explain this further, please?

Comment: @Brian Have to get libraries reviewed by my manager before using it. Work in finance industry, hence too many regulations I guess. I am sure one of the libraries will be approved, but need to resolve this sooner than that. Is this what I am trying to do a huge undertaking?

Comment: @user793468 - It's not a 'huge' undertaking, necessarily, but it **could** quickly become that depending on how robust you need the validation to ultimately be. Also, as was mentioned above, there are so many freebie libraries out there that having to essentially code this yourself, by hand, seems silly.  You may tell your boss that I said this :P

Comment: @Brian haha, yes I will forward your regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar enough with MVC to answer about how to use built-in validation (like plain-old ASP.Net has), assuming that MVC has it to begin with.

That little disclaimer out of the way, the code below should validate your form for required fields and throw a message on the page for your users:

```
$(function () {
    var Validate = function Validate(e) {
        var allFieldsValid = false, // boolean flag to cache result
            invalidFields = [],     // array for selectors
            validFields = [],       // array for selectors
            requiredFields = [      // array of selectors to validate against
                "#Code",
                "#Description",
                "#Status"
            ],
            message = $('<span />').addClass('validation-message').text('* This is a required field.');
        $(requiredFields.join(', ')).each(function (i, elem) {
            //requiredFields.join(', ') should return "#Code, #Description, #Status"
            var field = $(elem)
                value = field.val();
            if (value.length === 0) {
                invalidFields.push(field.selector);
            } else {
                validFields.push(field.selector);
            }
        });
        allFieldsValid = invalidFields.length === 0;            // if there are no invalid fields, all fields must be valid
        $('span.validation-message').remove();                  // remove any previous validation messages
        $(validFields.join(', ')).removeClass("highlighted");   // remove class from all valid fields
        // add class to all invalid fields and append message
        $(invalidFields.join(', ')).addClass("highlighted").append(message.clone());
        if (!allFieldsValid) {
            e.preventDefault(); // invalid fields, prevent event from bubbling
        }
        return allFieldsValid;  // return result
    };
    $("#Save").click(Validate);
});
```

As far as your other questions about validation:

1. What is the best way of doing validations? Client side vs server side?
2. also, is it better to display a pop-up validation message or a highlighted message embedded on webpage?

In order:

1. **There is no versus**. There is either server-side, or both client-side and server-side. This is because you cannot rely on your users to have JavaScript enabled and therefore you cannot rely on your client-side to run. Think of client-side like a pre-filter. The purpose of client-side is to do a "precheck" and prevent unwanted data from using up bandwidth (sending to server and the "bad data" response) and from using processing cycles on the server. Client-side will also be more responsive than server-side (because there's no request-response) but that's really only a perceived performance issue for high-latency connections. **Server-side will always run and so validation should always start on the server.**
2. This is matter of preference for your users. Personally, I wouldn't code a pop-up unless someone asked me very nicely to do so, mostly because it takes focus away from the form and requires extra work (usually one click) to dismiss. A highlighted message does not have to do either of these, and some validation routines are even nice enough to put focus on the first invalid field. If there's room on the page for it, a message next to each field is handy and can look very nice. If however, space on the page is at a premium, most validation routines will put an asterisk next to the field and have all of the individual validation messages in one spot on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Just add place holders for your error message in your HTML.  For example:

```
    <td>
        <input id="Description" type="text"/><span id="descriptionErrorPlaceholder" />
    </td>
```

Then in your javascript, use jQuery or regular javascript to add your warning message.

```
$("#descriptionErrorPlaceholder").text("Warning message");
```

Answer (score 1):

after your table you can keep a div without anything written in it. but with an id.

And after you validaten just access that div by document.get('div_id') and then assign value to it.

Using this you can even show validation with colors like red and others.
And showing like this is better than a popup because when a softaware comes number of cliks should be minimum.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using jQuery, you may be able to get approval to user the jQuery Validation plug-in, since it comes standard with Microsoft MVC applications now whenever you start a new project. That being said, I do recognize how hard it can be to get plug-ins approved, since I'm supporting different government clients. It looks like you could add a  tag with each input element, and then modify the class for that span to show and hide it, similar to what you already do when highlighting the input box.

I can't test this on my work machine, but I would think it's something like:

```
$(function () {

    $("#Save").click(Validate);

});

function Validate() {

var invalidValues = [];
var validValues = [];
var Code = $("#Code").val();
var Description = $("#Description").val();
var Status = $("#Status ").val();    

var requiredFields = { '#Code' : Code,
                         '#Description' : Description,
                         '#Status ' : Status };

    $.each(requiredFields, function (key, value) {
        if (value.length == 0) {
            invalidValues.push(key);
        }
        else { validValues.push(key); }
    });

        var invalidFields = invalidValues.toString();
        var validFields = validValues.toString();

    if (invalidValues.length > 0){
        $(invalidFields).addClass("highlighted");
        $(validFields).removeClass("highlighted");  

        $(invalidFields + "Validator").addClass("showValidation");
        $(invalidFields + "Validator").removeClass("hideValidation");
        return false;
    }
    $(validFields).removeClass("highlighted");
    $(validFields + "Validator").removeClass("showValidation");
    $(invalidFields + "Validator").addClass("hideValidation");
}
```

With the HTML

```
<div>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Code
        </th>
        <td>
           <input maxlength="4" id="Code" type="text"/><span id="CodeValidator" class="hideValidation" />
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>
            Description
        </th>
        <td>
            <input id="Description" type="text"/><span id="DescriptionValidator" class="hideValidation" />
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>
            Status
        </th>
        <td>
            <input id="Status" type="text"/><span id="StatusValidator" class="hideValidation" />
        </td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>  
        <th>
    </th>      
        <td>
            <button id="Save" type="button">Save</button>
        </td>        
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```